# difference between "American" and "an American"

Tags: meaning, grammar

When I ask someone's nationality, he or she answers "I am American or I am an American.  I think both are right for me. Could anyone tell me which one is better ?

Comment: Why would one of them be better? Sometimes there's more than one way to say something.

Answer (score 2):

*American* is an adjective, so *I'm American* has a predicate **adjective**, with an auxiliary form of *be*. 
However, it can also be a noun, so *I'm an American* has a predicate **noun**, with an auxiliary  *be*.

Neither one is more correct than the other. It's precisely the difference between saying

- *I'm French/German/Danish/Spanish*
  and saying
- *I'm a Frenchman/a German/a Dane/a Spaniard.*

Sometimes the name for a nationality is the same as the name for a person of that nationality.
And sometimes it's not.